# Swipebox slide with next previous icon

Tags: jquery, swipe, slide, mobile-website, photoswipe

I am using swipebox it is easy and useful.
In [demo](http://brutaldesign.github.io/swipebox/) there is all slide images and when click any image it show slide.

I want to destroy click and i want to show slide in first time-default.

I will show first image with next-previous icon.When user click-swipe next image slide will show next image.My needed design is here 
[image]

I modified photoswipe.js

i change

```
$(document).on('click', selector, function (event) {
```

with

```
$(document).on('Load', selector, function (event) {
```

but it does not work
any workaround solution?

I don't want fullscreen,transparent background for slide.
I just want to show one image with next and previous icon.When user click next and previous it show next-previous image.

here is my view code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.swipebox').swipebox();
    });
</script>

<div class="content">
    <div class="display-img" style="overflow: hidden; text-align: center;">

                foreach (var item in Model.Images.Take(8))
        {

                <a rel="gallery-1" href="@item.Url" class="swipebox" >
                <img src="@item.ThumbnailUrl" alt="image" style="width:22%;height:35%;">
            </a> 



        }
        <div class="specifications">
            @if (ViewBag.Culture == "tr")
            {
                <img src="~/Content/images/display_foot_bg.png" width="280" />

            }
            else
            {
                <img src="~/Content/images/display_foot_bg2.png" width="280" />
            }
        </div>
```

edited:
with [darren sweeney](https://stackoverflow.com/users/973552/darren-sweeney) answears i

i added this code to view

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.swipebox').swipebox();
        $('.swipebox:first').click();
         // simply faking a click on the selector which starts the slide

    });
</script>
```

not it works.Without click any images it show slide.

But i need page like this:https://i.stack.imgur.com/xBWMO.png 
not like this [image]

because there is information-content-links and other html control in my page.Slide is just a part of my mobile web site page.So i need change slide full screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you have initialized it you can start it..

```
Code.photoSwipe('a', '#Gallery');
Code.PhotoSwipe.Current.show(0);
```

**UPDATE** IGNORE above, the simplest option is this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('.swipebox').swipebox();
    $(selector).click(); // simply faking a click on the selector which starts the slide
  });
</script>
```

Comment: where i add this code?what is code?should i replace your code with this? <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.swipebox').swipebox();
    });
</script>

Comment: i add my view code to my question, i edited my question

Comment: Updated my answer, try that

Comment: it does not work.it give error in browser console : Uncaught ReferenceError: selector is not defined        shoulde i add any scripts for selector?i included jquery and  <script src="~/Content/imgSlider/photoswipe.js"></script>

Comment: In you original post you had: `$(document).on('click', selector, function (event) {` replace `selector` with whatever is `selector` in that

Comment: i choose first selector for click  but it is fullscreen   <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.swipebox').swipebox();
        $('.swipebox:first').click();
         // simply faking a click on the selector which starts the slide
        
    });
</script>

Comment: what do you click to start the slider? is it a button? a link? whichever, does it have an id? or at least a unique class?

Comment: Your code works for me.selector or click problem solved.Now i need change slide fullscreen.i edited question..can you look questions edited part please

Comment: Please accept this as the answer and start a new question and I'll take a look - don't want to start adding to questions

Comment: i asked here   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29266309/swipebox-slide-with-html-control-and-content-instead-of-popup