# Swipebox slide with html control and content instead of popup

Tags: jquery, swipe, slide, mobile-website, photoswipe

I am using swipebox it is easy and useful.I want show first image with next-previous icon.When user click(or touch-swipe in mobile) next image slide will show next image.My needed design is here

[image]
as you can see in my design there is slide and also there is many other html control-content-div-buton......

but swipebox show pop up and it just show slide as below.
This is not good for me because there is information-content-links and other html control in my page(design).Slide is just a part of my mobile web site page.So i need change slide full screen and pop

[image]

here is my view code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.swipebox').swipebox();
    $('.swipebox:first').click();
     // simply faking a click on the selector which starts the slide

});
```

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="display-img" style="overflow: hidden; text-align: center;">

                foreach (var item in Model.Images.Take(8))
        {

                <a rel="gallery-1" href="@item.Url" class="swipebox" >
                <img src="@item.ThumbnailUrl" alt="image" style="width:22%;height:35%;">
            </a> 



        }
        <div class="specifications">
            @if (ViewBag.Culture == "tr")
            {
                <img src="~/Content/images/display_foot_bg.png" width="280" />

            }
            else
            {
                <img src="~/Content/images/display_foot_bg2.png" width="280" />
            }
        </div>
```

Comment: Does swipebox even do that? What you need is a carousel - will it do carousel too?

Comment: i think no because no document about that

Answer (score 0):

I just tried venobox to display content with the image using inline; works perfect for me. http://lab.veno.it/venobox/